# Any way to turn off the black lines in curve edit mode?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, bezier-curves

Is there any way to turn off the black lines in curve *Edit Mode*?

[image: is there any way to turn off the black lines in curve edit mode?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure thing.

These lines show the *Normals* orientation.
Just uncheck the corresponding field in the *Viewport Overlays* panel.
You can also adjust their length with the slider.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think these are normals and it can be turned of in the right top corner under viewport overlays, in this menu at the bottom is curve edit mode, where is option box to show normals.